# passing multiple variables to pthread in a loop; arguments get overwritten next iteration

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, global-variables

I had a problem with threads producing garbage and I think I found the problem and I'm hoping someone can confirm or refute my suspicion and recommend the best solution.

Then in the thread dispatch function there was

```
/*global variables*/
struct passArgs
{
    int length;
    char match;
    char** data;
};
```

In thread dispatch funcion...

```
struct passArgs args;
pthread_t thrd[ALPHA_LENGTH];
    args.data = data;
    args.length = tt;
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHA_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        args.match = (char)(i+65);
    pthread_create(&thrd[i], NULL, &processData, &args))
    }
```

This didn't work because by the time `processData()` red the arguments being passed by the struct into local variables they had been overwritten by the next iteration of the for loop.

Solution 1: create an array of structs.

```
struct passArgs args[ALPHA_LENGTH];
for(int i = 0; i < ALPHA_LENGTH; i++)
{
    args[i].data = data;
    args[i].length = tt;
    args[i].match = (char)(i+65);
}
```

In the function `processData()` this produced the compilation errors "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type".

processData creates the local variables from the structs as follows

```
struct passArgs *myArgs = (struct passArgs *)ptrToArgs;
char** words = (*myArgs).data;
const int length = (*myArgs).length;
const char responsibleFor = (*myArgs).match;
```

Solution 2: move the struct to the global variable section. This seemed to work but I know global variables should be avoided. I also don't understand why this worked?

Comment: What is `proc()` here?. The compilation errors are probably due to the struct definition being placed after the usage.

Comment: @mnunberg the function that is passed to the thread

Comment: Ahh sorry, didn't see it's the thread entry point

Comment: @mnunberg I just renamed it to hopefully a more meaningful name

Comment: Well, you're right about the structure being overidden by the loop. But it's essentially a race condition on how quickly the thread can spawn and read the variable before it's wiped out and continues to the next iteration. The fact that it might work in a global variable? perhaps because the access is quicker?

Comment: Solution 1 is the best way to go.  The compilation error probably arises because `processData()` could not see a definition of the structure type.  Why that was the problem depends on how you wrote the code.

Comment: @mnunberg compilation errors occurred if it wasn't a global variable

Comment: you had first share one variable between threads,then try to use one variable for each thread."incomplete" error might caused for using opaque data type for your structure and the inner format is not clear for compiler. Make the definition clear for your thread procedure.

Comment: @Celeritas what do you think about using synchronization structures such as semaphores, maybe after initialization of parameters, the thread may signal to main the job done?